# Opengl/glsl : Pass float array to shader by texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am trying to pass a float* that contains 128*128 float to a shader. Since this array is too big, I am trying to pass by a texture to get my float* in my shader. The problem is I don't know how to use this array inside my shader.
I print my float* before sending it to my shader, and It contains number between -1 and 1.

My goal is to simulate waves on water with perlin noise, so my array of float is perlin noises.

So I instantiate my noise texture like this :

```
_perlin_noise = new float[_dimension * _dimension];

//... I put float inside my _perlin_noise variable

//Then I instantiate my texture : 

glGenTextures(1, &_perlin_noise_text);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _perlin_noise_text);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32F, _dimension, _dimension, 0,
    GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, _perlin_noise);


glActiveTexture(0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

My water use two textures : One texture is full blue, the other is a texture of foam.
So now I have a third texture that is my perlin noise. And I want to ajust the height of my vertices by perlin noise.

So before anything, I alocate uniform variable to my shader like this :

```
main_water_shader->use();
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(main_water_shader->getProgram(), "main_water_texture"), 0);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(main_water_shader->getProgram(), "foam_texture"), 1);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(main_water_shader->getProgram(), "perlin_noise"), 2);
```

Then I want to ajust vertices's height in my vertex shader, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to do that in my vertex shader :

```
uniform sampler2D perlin_noise;
//some other uniform...

void main()
{
    //calculating vertex height
    float height = float( texture2D(perlin_noise, vec2(x, y)) ); 
    vec3 new_vertex_position = vertex_position;
    new_vertex_position.y = height;

    //Standard stuff
    vs_position = vec4(ModelMatrix * vec4(new_vertex_position, 1.f)).xyz;
    vs_texcoord = vec2(vertex_texcoord.x, vertex_texcoord.y );
    vs_normal = mat3(ModelMatrix) * vertex_normal;

    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix  * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(new_vertex_position, 1.f);
}
```

Nothing change, the height of my vertices is still the same. And if I try to display my perlin_noise texture in my fragment shader onto a plan, I get this :

[image]

You can see my plane (which is very large) with a black and white texture on it that is repeated. So I guess my perlin_noise texture does contains something (even if it is a bit weird), but I can't figure out how to use it in my vertex shader.

EDIT : In my screenshoot, I also use a vertex shader with height ajusted with perlin noise, but as you can see, my plane is plane, so It does not seems to work.

EDIT2 : If I'm not clear enough, tell me

Comment: The vertex shader is executed once for each vertex (for each corner point of a primitive. Try `texture2D(perlin_noise, vec2(x, y) / 128.0);`

Comment: Also, since `y` seems to be height, you should probably be use `vec2(x, z) / 128.0`.  Your vertex shader has variables `x` , `y`, and `z` but you haven't told us how these are computed.

Comment: you are both right, It solve my problem. Thanks